# PocketC GUI Code Examples

Tags: user-interface, runtime, windows-ce, pocketc

I'm using [PocketC](http://orbworks.com/pcce/index.html) on my Windows CE device, but I want to know where I can find some code examples of GUIs, because I don't know where to get help on this point.

Also, I have some specify questions:

- How to create Buttons, ListBoxes...?
- What are the controls supported?
- How to create menus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the [examples they provide on their site](http://orbworks.com/pcce/resources.html) like [Reversi](http://orbworks.com/wince/example/reversi/index.html)?

It's a proprietary tool that according to their own site "is no longer being supported or maintained" so I'm guessing that the number of people worldwide who could even provide you examples could be counted on one hand.  Those that would be willing to and reading this question would be even smaller.

Seriously, other that as a science experiment, why would you even go down this road?

Comment: The Reversi and Sokoban games have buttons.  The calendar has lists.  You're going to have to look at the code for those to see how it's done.  I can't imagine you're going to find any sort of tutorials for this thing.

Comment: Could you please answer to the bullets that I've just added?